# Display Analytics From Custom Database Piwik

Tags: matomo

I want to write a plugin which will connect to my custom database (not piwik database) and display the analytics(graphs, tables) on piwik website. I am referring to this tutorial which is the only one available

http://amirshk.com/blog/2011/07/08/piwik-custom-data-tracking/

Is there any other tutorial that explains to connect plugin to custom database and display analytics?